# A repo that is making it not possible to update with sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I have tried to get php 8.0 but it was a pain so I want it removed which I did. Now when I update I get this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 https://packages.sury.org/php focal InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease                                                                                                    
Err:4 https://packages.sury.org/php focal Release                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.18.148 443]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages [2992 B]
Get:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [57.0 kB]
Get:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages [7720 B]
Get:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6888 B]
Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [2804 B]
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted Translation-en [47.8 kB]
Reading package lists... Done            
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried to read forums on how to delete repos but I didn't know the name of the repo. I can install and purge just fine but updating is the main problem.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit your question and copy and paste the code and do not post a screenshot. Posting a screenshot is a good way to have your question ignored. Paste the output into the question, highlight the code and then press CTRL+K to automatically format it as code. Thanks.

Comment: The [readme.txt](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt) suggest the file is named `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list`

Comment: @bac0n Thanks I found the package link thing in there like this  `deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ focal main` which I believe is the repo link i'm looking for. Though would I remove php.list or just the repo?

Comment: it works fine actually without the files I will write an answer and refer your comment thanks

Comment: the dist is stretch buster or bullseye suggests it's suited for debian and not ubuntu. (yes you can delete it)

Comment: that makes a lot of sense thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, for example, with nano editor:

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then comment the lines with the "sury" repo, adding a `#` at the beginning of the line.

Then come back to the terminal, and repeat the `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: I've looked for surry but I can't find it

Comment: Then, check if that repo is into the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (ending with a ".d"). What is the output of `ls` command into that directory?

Comment: I checked that file like what @bac0n said and deleted the php file repo and it works superb

Comment: Yes, that's it! By the way, you can upvote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote it sorry